# How to pass DateTimeOffset parameters to oData functions

Tags: .net, function, odata, asp.net-web-api2, datetimeoffset

I have an odata function called GetForPeriod defined as:

```
        var getForPeriod =
            builder.EntityType<EventModel>()
                .Collection
                .Function("GetForPeriod")
                .ReturnsCollection<EventModelSummary>();
        getForPeriod.Parameter<DateTimeOffset>("from");
        getForPeriod.Parameter<DateTimeOffset>("to");
```

So to get results from the function, I need to call:

`http://localhost:17257/odata/Events/Default.GetForPeriod(from=2015-12-27T00:00:00-06:00,to=2016-02-06T00:00:00-06:00)`

But I keep getting an error stating:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

The problem is the dates, as if I do 
`http://localhost:17257/odata/Events/Default.GetForPeriod(from=null,to=null)`
I get an error stating that it can't convert null to a DateTimeOffset (which makes sense).

I tried replacing the colon (:) in the from and two values to **%3A**, but I still get the same dangerous path error.

Interesting enough, if I call the read path for events with a date filter it works fine.
`http://localhost:17257/odata/Events?$filter=ScheduledDate%20ge%202015-12-27T00:00:00-06:00%20and%20ScheduledDate%20le%202016-02-06T00:00:00-06:00`

How am I supposed to call an OData function which takes a datetime offset for a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the function parameter alias?

From OData spec:

*A parameter alias can be used in place of an inline parameter to a function call. The value for the alias is specified as a separate query option using the name of the parameter alias.*

*Example 76: invoke a Sales.EmployeesByManager function via the function import EmployeesByManager, passing 3 for the ManagerID parameter*

```
http://host/service/EmployeesByManager(ManagerID=@p1)?@p1=3
```

The same issue is tracked on https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/204

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="%" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Seems unlikely because the OP's `filter=ScheduledDate%20` URL works, while their `GetForPeriod` has no %s and doesn't work. Note that this affects the settings for your [entire site](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_aspnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous_request_path.htm).

Comment: This answer is saying that the '%' is INVALID... that is why this is a potential solution for OP, because ':' has been removed from the list, the time components should be allowed.

Comment: Still relevant today (2021), didn't realise I had previously commented!

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a `web.config` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```